# how can we set different colors to highcharts-default-patterns?

Tags: highcharts, react-highcharts

I want to show diagonal striped patterns of desired color in stacked column bar graph. i am using default pattern url(#highcharts-default-pattern-0) for it, but unable to change color of it as i want this pattern in various colors.

For reference i am attaching image which i want to achieve using diagonal stripes.[image: diagonal-striped-columns]

I tried to achieve it using [pattern-fills](https://www.highcharts.com/blog/tutorials/pattern-fills/) but was unable to get it.

Please provide your valuable inputs. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi @Atul, What problem did you encounter using `pattern-fill` module? Here everything works: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0etopfLs/

Comment: Thank you @ppotaczek for your reply, Actually initially i was unaware of SVG creation, so i was not able to understand it. later on i read about SVG Creation and it's patterns then it become clearer to me. But you have shared good jsfiddle example, i appreciate. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way is to use the official `pattern-fill` module:

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        color: {
            pattern: {
                path: {
                    d: 'M 0 0 L 10 10 M 9 -1 L 11 1 M -1 9 L 1 11',
                    strokeWidth: 2
                },
                width: 10,
                height: 10,
                opacity: 0.4
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0etopfLs/

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/blog/tutorials/pattern-fills/